# Do neutron stars reflect light?

Tags: electromagnetism, astrophysics, nuclear-physics, neutron-stars

The setup is very simple: you have a regular ($1.35$ to $2$ solar masses) evolved neutron star, and you shine plane electromagnetic waves on it with given $\lambda$. Very roughly, what shall be the total flux of absorbed/scattered EM radiation?

Shall the result change if the neutron star is young and not evolved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A neutron star will have a thin layer of normal matter at the surface, and of course this reflects light just like any other normal matter.

But I guess you're really asking if neutronium reflects light, and that's a very good question that a quick Google failed to answer. EM radiation generally interacts with dipoles or scatters off electrons, so I'd guess matter made of neutrons should be transparent.

Comment: AFAIK, `neutron star` $\neq$ `neutronium`, `neutronium` $\implies$ " $n$ revolving around $\bar{n}$ atoms". `Neutron star`\implies "pure $n$ with atomic matter shell.

Comment: Scratch that, neutronium=pure neutrons. Wierd--the rest of the particles become particle-antiparticle pairs when appended with [-onium](http://enwp.org/Onium).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the reference, it is actually very relevant!

Comment: Would the index of refraction be the same as vacuum or would it be a giant lens?  [This comment](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/711/if-i-shine-a-bright-light-on-a-neutron-star-what-would-it-look-like#comment666_728) says the magnetic moment of the neutrons could still interact with EM?

Comment: There would be a reasonable gravitational redshift near the surface of a star - so you would expect it to red-en the reflected light

Comment: @Martin, probably, you wouldn't, because there will be a comparable blue-shift of the incident light.

Comment: Link to astronomy.SE page redirects to an unrelated answer (on question 220).

Comment: Thanks. The link must have been broken when the Astronomy SE closed then reopened as a beta.

Comment: Neutron stars *don't* just consist of neutrons even in their interiors. I believe this makes your guess wrong. There are plenty of (free) electrons inside neutron stars.

Comment: @RobJeffries: to be fair I did refine the question to whether *neutronium* reflects light or not. You point out that the interior of real neutron stars isn't pure neutronium, which I didn't know but seems plausible, but we've already established that a real neutron star reflects light because its surface is reflective.

Comment: Why would neutron stars be reflective? They are usually assumed to be near-perfect black bodies and therefore absorb almost all light incident upon them. If the surface was reflective, neutron stars would be unable to cool through radiative processes.

Comment: @RobJeffries: I meant *reflective* in the sense of having a non-zero reflectivity. Whether the reflectivity is 0.1% or 99.9% I don't know, and anyway that isn't the interesting thing about the question. What's interesting is what the optical properties of (pure) neutronium would be.

Comment: The question does not ask about neutronium, which does not exist inside neutron stars. Your answer is vague about the reflective properties of the surface - everything bar a black hole has a reflectivity somewhere between 0 and 100%.

Comment: I was not aware until now that "neutronium" normally refers to something other than "neutron-star degenerate matter", though I knew the term had been used for "nucleii containing only neutrons".

Answer (score 9):

Neutron stars are usually assumed to have intrinsic spectra that approximate  closely to black bodies - though the details are many and need a full consideration of the strong magnetic fields and electrodynamics near the surface. They have a thin layer (few cm) of non-degenerate, gaseous material at their surfaces, rich in ionised or partially ionised iron-peak elements. However, accretion from the ISM possibly means that most neutron stars have a skin of hydrogen or helium present.

Modelling of neutron star atmospheres is well established (I found this review by [Potehkin (2014)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.0074) extremely useful). Isolated, non-magnetic neutron stars have spectra that are close, but not identical to black bodies.There can be absorption features if there are significant densities of iron-peak elements in the atmosphere. H/He atmosphere have spectra shifted towards higher energies. Strong magnetic fields introduce more complications, including cyclotron absorption lines. In these models the neutron star is unlikely to be very reflective because by definition, something that approximates a blackbody absorbs most radiation incident upon it. Some isolated neutron stars have now been observed at X-ray wavelengths and their spectra are close to blackbodies with some evidence for broad absorption features that might be due to cyclotron lines (e.g. [Haberl 2005](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005fysx.conf...39H)).

*However*, there is an idea that in some neutron stars, the outer atmosphere may be cool enough and/or the magnetic field strong enough to cause a phase transition to a solid state just below a very thin hydrogen atmosphere ([Turolla et al. 2004](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2004ApJ...603..265T)). In these circumstances the surface can become (partially) reflective. [Potekhin et al.(2012)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2012A%26A...546A.121P) considered a condensed iron surface in strong magnetic fields ($10^{12}-10^{14}\ G$) covered by a very thin atmosphere. They find certain photon energy ranges where the reflectivity can reach of order 50 percent.

Older neutron stars will have lower temperatures and probably lower magnetic fields. The ionisation state of the atmosphere will change and the effects of magnetic fields would diminish.

Comment: Hm, generally, one assumes a general statement first and then argues for a particular one. For example, one would generally expect even optically thick media to be reflective, and indeed why would it not scatter some of the incident light back?

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick Yes, I expect there will be small, wavelength dependent departures from black body behaviour, just as there are for other stellar atmospheres. I suppose it depends what you mean by "some". What ionised gases are highly reflective?

Comment: Highly - none, but reflection coefficient of 0.1-0.2 is not that small either. Consider clouds - they are not ionised, granted, but are opaque and rather reflective. Why would dense neutron star atmosphere not be similarly reflective?

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick So you are saying that if I shine a laser (plane EM wave as per the question) at a "cloud" I will receive 10-20% of the radiation back?? No. And neither can a cloud be considered a black body, whereas a neutron star can (to a good approximation).

Comment: I was having in mind something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_albedo . The laser probably would be better reflected if it were tuned at some of the absorption lines. And yes, it is not a black body. But black body approximation is used for getting emission and due to the fact that neutron star's atmosphere is optically thick at the wavelengths it is emitting.

Answer (score 3):

A neutron star is mostly neutrons, but it contains protons to a certain extent allowed by the gravity, since a pure neutron state is unstable to beta decay. The protons collect on the surface due to their electrostatic repulsion, and form a fermi-gas like state there.

The fermi-gas of protons will reflect long-wavelength light very much like an ordinary metal-- the surface will, if you scrape off the ordinary matter, be shiny like a mirror.

Comment: Neutron star remains neutral due to charge conservation, so macroscopic motion of protons due to electrostatic forces will not happen. Another point to mention is that neutron stars have to have an atmosphere, as the surface pressure contiuously drops to zero (otherwise the surface would expand until the outer pressure gets to zero). Hence close to the surface in a thin layer there will be all sorts of physical states of matter. One definite conclusion from all this and from what you say, indirectly, is that neutron stars are not transparent.

Comment: @AlexeyBobrick:yes, I agree, the electron gas neutralizing the proton is also like a metal. So you have two charged fluids reflecting light, it's still shiny once you scrape the ordinary matter off.

Comment: This is right. Though the atmosphere could make it look lika a metal in a thin hydrogen cloud, with some wierd layers in between (strong magnetic field, high gradients of species distribution, etc.)

Comment: The problem here is that free protons don't gather on the surface. They recombine with electrons to form neutrons. The surfaces of neutron stars probably consist of non-degenerate, partially ionised, iron-peak nuclei and free electrons.

Comment: @RobJeffries: Their is an equilibrium density of protons among the neutrons, because neutron purification by gravitational instability is never perfect. The extra protons collect on the surface. The ordinary matter is a separate thing, forming what is called an "atmosphere" over the neutron star surface. The nuclear ball contains a proton fraction in thermodynamic equilibrium through beta decay.

Comment: Neutron stars have an atmosphere, then they have a crust (up to several km thick), and only interior to this do you encounter free protons in the n,p,e fluid. https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/objects/binaries/neutron_star_structure.html

Comment: @RobJeffries: True, but the question was asking about what you would see if you could bounce light off the neutron star surface, not off the ordinary matter crust. The protons are the charged reflectors capable of motion, and these free charges is what is dominating the reflection properties of the surface. Sure, the crust would be different, but the question was about the nuclear material inside. It might be possible to ask this properly by imagining blasting off the normal matter and looking fast, before it has a chance to reform, or by using a gamma that can penetrate the outer layers.

Comment: @RonMaimon that isn't what the question asks. And, even if it were, there is no way to accurately describe where the crust begins and ends - what about the nuclear pasta phase? You might be right about the reflectivity of that being high (though you cannot observe it) but nothing I have ever seen talks about some kind of proton concentration gradient in the npe fluid.

Comment: @RobJeffries: The model is a neutron ball with a proton gradient, I don't know about the theoretical status of the nuclear pasta models, they are high-temperature models as far as I can see, relevant only during collapse, not low temperature models. The other answer explained the crust, I just explained the general phenomenon of reflectivity in a free conducting surface. A neutron ball has a proton gradient with a free conductive surface, regardless of what other people say. As I understand it, this is the right model for a cold neutron star, with a sharp phase transition at the crust.

Answer (score 2):

Martin, the infalling light is blue-shifted, and red-shifted on reflection. No overall change, I think.
However, a suitably mechanically strong light-source on the surface of the neutron star (!) will be seen to emit light that is redder than usual.

If the neutron star had its normal matter scraped off (left as an exercise for the student) then I don't see how light would interact at all with it. Hard gamma rays would be absorbed, but anything else? Nah.

Comment: Neutrons have a dipole moment, and there is a proton gas density in neutron stars, which should reflect light like a shiny metal.

Comment: Same comment as for the accepted answer. Neutron stars contain plenty of free protons and electrons. They would be utterly opaque to light. Whether they would be reflective is a different matter. You certainly can't scrape the normal matter off, because more normal matter would form - like a tarnish perhaps.

Comment: Would there also be a layer of white dwarf matter between the neutron matter and the normal matter?