# Would electron degenerate matter be a good x-ray reflector?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection, x-rays

I do not know much about x-ray physics *or* degenerate matter, but I have the intuitive feeling that the high electron density and what must be some crazy band structures in electron degenerate matter might give rise to a high x-ray reflectivity. So as a purely hypothetical question that suddenly struck me; does anyone who *does* know something about these topics think that you could bounce x-rays of white dwarfs?

Comment: Closely related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89330/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57632/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22722/. Surely we have a good answer somewhere...

Comment: I couldn't find an answer there, but thanks for pointing them out. All those questions concern neutron stars/neutron degenerate matter, and the answers more or less assume no electrons or simply says that there will be a surface of "normal matter".
I'm wondering about the (high energy) optical effects of the weird electronic structure of electron degenerate matter.